# Can Angular Service Reference it's Initiator?

Tags: angular

Consider two injectable services: `UsersService` and `AdminUserService extends UserService`.
`UserService` has some initialisation process applied in it's constructor.
But since `AdminUserService` calls `super()`, `UserService`'s constructor is *being called twice*.
Please accept this pattern as a fact since I can not change it at the moment.

My question is: **Can `UserService`'s constructor know who invoked it and act accordingly?**

Comment: Is `UserService` and Injectable? Is `UserService` abstract?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then it's not possible. It would result in a CircularDependency

Comment: @JSONDerulo both are injectables

Answer (score 1):

You can easily access the  instance of the object in  the parent constructor and check the name of it's constructor, which will reflect the name of the class that was instantiated.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("I am", this.constructor.name);
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {super();}
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {super();}
}

var a = new Child1();
var b = new Child2();
```

Though the real question would be - why would you need to do that? I think the fact that  you need to access that information in the parent class infers you need to rethink your design. Perhaps move some of that instantiation logic outside of parent? Perhaps make the Parent abstract, give it abstract method that will be called in the constructor and then have children implement that method accordingly? See snippet above:

```
abstract class Parent {
  constructor() {
    doSomethingInConstructor();
  }
  
  abstract doSomethingInConstructor(): void;
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  doSomethingInConstructor(): void {
    console.log("I do something as Child 1");
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  doSomethingInConstructor(): void {
    console.log("I do something else, since I'm a Child 1");
  }
}

var a = new Child1();
var b = new Child2();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get by this by moving your initialization logic from the constructor to a factory method, and then you can have multiple factories depending on how you create the service.